# Using Html Anchor on my web site

Tags: css, html, weebly

I am using weebly site builder and so just a beginner on Html coding. I am having issues making anchors work on my pages. They seem to work on some systems and not others, and so I think there must be a better method.

Here is what I am doing

I have a guest author page and I want each guest, to have a direct link to his section of the web page

I set up an anchor as follows

Then use the following link to it
http://arthurvaso.weebly.com/guests2016.html/#smith2

On some computers/broswers this works just fine, in others, it just goes to the Top of the page instead of the section I want.

I basically have pages I want to make direct links to

Poet1
Poet2
Poet3  etc

I search here, an all the posts were either  years old, or not exactly the answer I was looking for. It seems the newer the browser version, the less my method works.

I really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: You should to put the code related to your issue in the question itself. How you define the anchors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little trick to it, but it's an easy fix for you. You are missing `&nbsp;` in your Anchor.

Change:

```
<a id="smith2"></a>
```

To:

```
<a id="smith2">&nbsp;</a>
```

Make sure to publish the changes.

And, note that your Anchor Link should be:
 http://arthurvaso.weebly.com/guests2016.html#smith2 
**without the / after .html**

Comment: I made the change, and tested on Apple Safari, Microsoft, Firefox, Chrome, old versions and new ones, android and voila it all worked. I didn't understand the logic of adding a space character, but it all worked. Of note, I didn't remove the / and it still worked, from testing it seems to work with or without the /